# Workflow and case management software

Tags: project-management, document-management, workflow

I am looking for software which will help me to manage big workflow of cases.

I have more than **100'000 cases**, each of them follow a workflow. I would like to manage case-flows with a software. There are more or less couple standard flows with 5-6 steps for each. There are no functions or advanced logic in every step. It is technically just a label. But labels should be assigned within the specific order of the flow. Every step has documents associated with it. I need to have a possibility to upload documents through API for every step in a case-flow.
[image]

Main requirements with API and WEB GUI:

- Multi-user environment `Admin` and `Manager`
- `Admin`: Add/Remove a user as "case-flow" manager role at any point a time.
- `Manager`: Move cases through flow
- `Manager`: Upload file-documents for every case-step
- `Manager`: There are associated float values with every case-step, i call them "costs". They can be different types and values for every case-step. I would like to upload and store them on case-step level.

Preferably self-hosted. Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[https://www.project-open.com](http://www.project-open.com) is open-source and includes a strong Petri-Net based workflow engine, a file-storage and a lot more. Please search Google for "project-open workflow" for documentation. The document upload tracking would require a custom workflow "transition". Disclaimer: I'm part of the ]po[ team.

Comment: Thanks! We're just after a relaunch. And we're all not native speakers...

Comment: Not unusual for FOSS projects (I'm involved in one myself!). ;)

Comment: Thanks, are there API functions to perform the tasks?

Comment: Hi, https://www.project-open.com/en/package-acs-workflow is the start point to the WF documentation, a tutorial is available here: https://www.project-open.com/en/tutorial-workflow. This is a very powerful engine (Petri-Nets allow for parallel tracks and you can mix user interaction with automatic tasks), but nobody said it would be easy. You could also just take the WF-Engine (entirely written in PL/SQL running _inside_ the PostgreSQL database - PG only...) and use it with a different front-end.